# PLAYWRIGHT: navigating to "/", waiting until "load" (React app)

Tags: typescript, playwright

Hi I am getting the same error all the time when I run the pipeline to pass the tests in my project. The error is as follows:
[image]

I don't know how to solve this problem, the playwright configuration file I have is the following:

```
import { defineConfig, devices } from "@playwright/test";

require("dotenv").config({ path: "./.env" });

/**
 * See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration.
 */
export default defineConfig({
    testDir: "./playwright/test",
    /* Ejecutar tests en ficheros en paralelo */
    fullyParallel: false,
    /* Falla la compilación en CI si accidentalmente dejaste test.only en el código fuente. */
    forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
    /* Reintentar sólo en CI */
    retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
    /* Optar por no realizar pruebas paralelas en CI. */
    workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
    /* Reportero a utilizar. Véasehttps://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
    reporter: "html",

    timeout: 120000,
    /* Ajustes compartidos para todos los proyectos a continuación. Véase https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
    use: {
        /* URL base para usar en acciones como `await page.goto('/')`. */
        baseURL: process.env.VITE_URL_FRONT,

        launchOptions: {
            slowMo: 500,
        },

        /* Recopilar trazas al reintentar la prueba fallida. Véase https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
        trace: "on-first-retry",

        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        extraHTTPHeaders: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "Content-Disposition",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        },
    },

    /* Configure projects for major browsers */
    projects: [
        {
            name: "chromium",
            use: { ...devices["Desktop Chrome"] },
        },

        {
            name: "firefox",
            use: { ...devices["Desktop Firefox"] },
        },

        {
            name: "webkit",
            use: { ...devices["Desktop Safari"] },
        },
    ],

    /* Ejecute su servidor de desarrollo local antes de iniciar las pruebas */
    webServer: {
        command: "npm run start",
        url: process.env.VITE_URL_FRONT,
        reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
    },
});
```

And in the .env file that I have it located in the root of the project I have the following:

[image]

Comment: This very much looks like the env var isn't making it to your PWT setup. [Is baseUrl defined](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/9439) when you use it in a test?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do:

```
await page.goto("./");
```